# Json path extraction with filters

Tags: json

I need to get the path of the element - list all the libraryphone numbers

I have the following json structure:

```
{
   library:[{
          libraryphone: 9898989898,
          location:{
              address:{
                   street:123 garden ave,
                   city: Dublin
              }
          },
         {
         libraryphone: 9090909090,
         location:{...}
        }, {
        libraryphone: 9797979797,
        location: {...}
       }
    }]
}
```

In the json above,  I have multiple library phones and addresses. So I need to collect all the phone numbers on the condition that the city exists. 
I have tried:

`$.library[?(@.location.address.city)].libraryphone`

I understand to get the libraryphones, all I need to do is

`$.library[*].libraryphone`

But, I need to have the condition of checking if the city exists or not.

Comment: Which language/tool do you use ?

Comment: For the tool, I use any online path evaluator to verify, posting the json

Comment: This is not valid JSON

Comment: Yes, I realise that. My question is how to frame that valid json with the filter and for all conditions

Comment: What is wrong with `$.library[?(@.location.address.city)].libraryphone`? It should work for walid `JSON` with presented structure.

Comment: Yes, but I get invalid path error